# Doubts on Hypothesis set?

Tags: machine-learning

Newbie to ML, i am having a hard time understanding what exactly is a hypothesis set.

From what i understand:

In Supervised Learning, we will be given Input, Output. We need to find a Hypothesis function which will be close to the Target function.

Now, to get from Example input(& output) to our Hypothesis function, we need Learning Algorithm. Now from what i read there is a component which goes into Learning Algorithm, which is Hypothesis set?!

Now what exactly is this Hypothesis set? Is this a set containing different Hypothesis functioin?

Comment: "*We need to find a Hypothesis function which will be close to the Target function.*" << You lost me here. Can you  please provide a reference you are trying to follow? Standard ML book references like Murphy (2012), Barber (2012), Hastie, Tibshirani & Friedman (2001) never mention anything on "hypothesis functions" so I am at loss as to what you are asking.

Comment: I am following "Learning From Data" MOOC, it's by Yaser S. Abu-Mostafa. What it means is that hypothesis function gives you the predicted answer, target function gives you the correct answer.

Comment: Thank for the clarification. For the record the phrase "hypothesis function" does not appear that book. Abu-Mostafa et al. refer to hypothesis sets...

Comment: @usεr11852 : My bad, yeah it's not hypothesis function, it's just hypothesis. Btw, what exactly is hypothesis set?

Comment: OK. See my answer below. BTW: Welcome to the CV community!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hypothesis set $H$ is the set of all candidate formulas  (or candidate models if you like) that could possibly explain the training examples we have.

Our learning algorithm $A$ (that being a straightforward learning routine like linear regression or an elaborate learning routine like a gradient boosting machine) allows us to make the optimal choice of $h \in H$ that the algorithm $A$ produces. Notice that the hypothesis test $H$ is related the learning algorithm $A$. For example, a linear regression can only "learn" linear models (if we do not incorporate interactions) while a gradient boosting machine can learn non-linear relations more easily.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the help mate, appreciate it! :)

Comment: Cool, no problem. I  am glad I could help. I added a small comment about how the choice of the learning algorithm affects our final hypothesis $h$.