# What is Hypothesis set in Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning

I am studying ML and I got a bit confused about what Hypothesis set (Hypothesis space) is, because there are various definitions given by various people.

**Short version:**

- What is a Hypothesis set and does it depend on ML algorithm? (if possible, please provide links to academic sources).
- How to find Hypothesis set size (cardinality)?

**Long version:**

1. According to [this answer to similar question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/304702), hypothesis space $\mathcal{H}$ is a set of *all possible* mappings from input space to {0, 1} (in binary classification case); indeed, if we have 4 features each having values {0, 1} and 1 response variable having values {0, 1}, we can create  $2^{2^4}=2^{16}=65536$ possible mappings or in other words possible hypotheses. So this answer claims that in the described case, $\mathcal{H} =$ {$h_1, h_2,\dots, h_{65536}$} and $|\mathcal{H}| = 65536$, and this solely depends on input space and possible responses, but does not depend on ML algorithm used..
2. However, [another answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/335276/209725), albeit talking about $\mathcal{H}$ being "set of all candidate formulas that could possibly explain the training examples", states that *"the hypothesis test $\mathcal{H}$ is related the learning algorithm $\mathcal{A}$."* This makes more sense: 2nd degree polynomial should have lesser $\mathcal{H}$ than 10th degree polynomial, as far as I understand it. According to this response, it's far from certain that $\mathcal{H} =$ {$h_1, h_2,\dots, h_{65536}$}; it rather depends on a specific chosen ML algorithm. Like, for algorithm $\mathcal{A}_1$ it's $\mathcal{H_1}$, for $\mathcal{A}_2$ it's $\mathcal{H_2}$, and $\mathcal{H_1}$ can be very different from $\mathcal{H_2}$.

And so, does $\mathcal{H}$ depend on learning algorithm, or is it just a set of all possible mappings from input space to responses which does not change from algorithm to algorithm?

As far as I understand $\mathcal{H}$ does depend on used algorithm because some algorithms physically cannot produce some hypotheses, thus their hypothesis set should be smaller than just "all possible mappings from inputs to responses", but I may be mistaken.

However, here another question arises. [This article](https://lirias.kuleuven.be/bitstream/123456789/298291/1/hyp-space.pdf) states that "hypothesis space used by a machine learning system is the set of  all hypotheses that might possibly be returned by it". Well, it claims that $\mathcal{H}$ does depend on algorithm, but when we think about how many of "all possible hypotheses" there are, we can say it's **infinitely many**. Isn't that so? Here, let's look at classification and regression:

1. Classification. Let's say we have 2 linearly separable classes, {-1, 1}. Let's use a Perceptron learning algorithm; to remind you, it learns and returns hypothesis in the form of $h($**x**$) = sign(\sum_{i=1}^{d}w_ix_i)$ where **x** is $d$-dimensional input vector. PLA returns us a line which separates between classes. Look at this picture (sorry for low quality as I now only have access to online paint so I had to draw by hand):
   [image: onemore]
   How many straight lines can be drawn between red and blue dots that separate them into 2 classes? Yes - **infinitely many**! So does that mean that hypothesis set of Perceptron is infinitely big ($|\mathcal{H}| = \mathfrak{c}$)?
2. Regression. It's even simpler: any given input vector x can be mapped not to just 2 values like in classification, but to any real number possible, which again makes $\mathcal{H}$ infinitely large. A linear regression can map an input vector to any real number, so does this mean that hypothesis set of Linear Regression is infinitely big?

This is what confuses me. I know that people compare hypothesis sets of various algorithms, saying that some $\mathcal{H_1}$ is small and $\mathcal{H}_2$ is big. So $\mathcal{H}$ has to be finite. But how can it be finite if you can draw infinite number of lines between 2 linearly separable sets of dots like in the picture above? You can yield infinite amount of different hypothese, doesn't it make Hypothesis set infinite?

The only thing I can think of is that $\mathcal{H}$ depends not only on learning algorithm but also on a particular parameters (i.e. choice of initial weights) and particular training set $\mathcal{D}$. If parameters and train set are fixed, then hypothesis set should be finite?..

So, **how do you determine cardinality of a particular $\mathcal{H}$?**

Simple examples of what is hypothesis set and how to find out its size are more than welcome..

Comment: It sounds like you'd be helped by the discussions of hypothesis spaces in [Tom Mitchell's _Machine Learning_](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~tom/mlbook.html). Welcome to CV!